# Is this $2d$ function injective and/or surjective?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Consider a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$  defined by $f(x,y)=(x,xy)$. Is this function injective, surjective? I can figure out that this is injective but cannot prove it surjective. Please help.

Comment: Why do you think it is injective?  $f(0,0)=(0,0)=f(0,1)$.

Comment: As a hint, is it true that for any real numbers $r,x$ there exists a $y$ such that $r=xy$?

Comment: Thank you lulu for pointing it out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do you believe that $f$ is surjective? That means for every $(z,w) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ there exists $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $f(x,y)=(z,w)$, i.e., $(x,xy)=(z,w)$. What would $x$ and $y$ have to be? Does this always work?

Comment: No it does not. so this means this mapping is neither injective nor surjective..

Comment: Right, it's not surjective. (And based on the comments above its not injective either.)